# "Uncaught Could not connect" error when using Openshift to deploy .war for PHP/Java bridge

Tags: java, php, ip, openshift, bridge

**Problem:** Recieve 'Could not connect' error when using Openshift to deploy .war for PHP/Java bridge

Below I describe every step I've taken to get to this error, thanks in advance.

**Full error:** (IP concealed)
"Fatal error: Uncaught Could not connect to the JEE server W.X.Y.Z:8080. Please start it. Or define('JAVA_HOSTS',9267); define('JAVA_SERVLET',false); before including 'Java.inc' and try again. Error message: Connection refused (111) thrown in /home/stevenw1/public_html/softwareProject/real/inc/Java.inc on line 989"

**Players:** "Java_Bridge.war" = my java .war file that php will use to call methods from
                 "W.X.Y.Z" = Unchanging IP address of deployed .war file
                 "GUIProfile" = a Java class with `@WebServlet("/GUIProfile")` as `public class GUIProfile extends HttpServlet`
                 "tomcattest.php" = test file that calls GUIProfile's static method 'validate'

**Deployed Java_Bridge.war and tomcattest.php work fine on my local tomcat, just not yet on Openshift.**

**Senario:**
0. followed command line steps from [Openshift 2012 java tomcat application](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kGotvToWeZI)
1. Using Openshift's rhc I have created my first app using "`rhc app create -a tomcat6 -t jbossews-1.0`"
2. `cd ~/tomcat6/; git rm -rf ./src/ pom.xml` 
3. `cp ~/Java_Bridge.war ./webapps/; git add ./webapps/Java_Bridge.war; git commit -m "first try"; git push`
//notable output includes:
          remote: Stopping jbossews cartridge
          remote: Sending SIGTERM to jboss:386662 ...
          remote: Skipping Maven build due to absence of pom.xml
          remote: Preparing build for deployment
          remote: Deployment id is bd83d6eb
          remote: Activating deployment
          remote: + '[' Java_Bridge.war ']'
          remote: Starting jbossews cartridge
          remote: Found W.X.Y.Z:8080 listening port                            //(not actual IP)
 
          remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
          remote: Activation status: success
          remote: Deployment completed with status: success
          to ssh://thisisnottheactualuser@tomcat6-notthenamehereeither.rhcloud.com

4. Thinking the .war was deployed I ran a tomcattest.php that calls a java method 'validate', from java class GUIProfile that extends httpservlet, using the php/java bridge Java.inc
//of course using the same IP from above...

```
cat tomcattest.php;

<?php

    define("JAVA_HOSTS", "W.X.Y.Z:8080");
    define("JAVA_SERVLET", "/Java_Bridge/GUIProfile");
    require_once("Java.inc");

    $valiationOutput = java_context()->getServlet()->validate("hello");

    echo $valiationOutput;

?>
```

EDIT: later tried this also in all instances: same results exactly

```
cat alternatetest.php
<?php

    define("JAVA_HOSTS", "W.X.Y.Z:8080");
    require_once("Java.inc");

    echo java("java.lang.System")->getProperties();

?>
```

The output of calling tomcattest.php is the 'Fatal error' you see at the top.

**Double Check:**
5. `ssh thisisnottheactualuser@tomcat6-notthenamehereeither.rhcloud.com`
6. `env | grep "IP"`
          OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_IP=W.X.Y.Z
7. `env | grep "PORT"`
          OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_HTTP_PORT=8080
          OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_JPDA_PORT=8787

8. changed port in tomcattest.php to 8787, didn't change a thing of course. 
9. restarted from the top, this time keeping ./src/ & pom.xml, same 'Deployment completed with status: success', same error using tomcattest.php with new listening IP...
10. tried solution from '[openshift youtube vid 2012](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=brbOcoJ-4Ic)' seemingly outdated. Followed step by step:
          onced ssh'ed, no "tomcat" dir, I used `cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` instead to access data dir
          wget tomcat, changed ports to >15000, `sh startup.sh && tail -f ../logs/*`
          notable errors in the result include:

> SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-15009]]
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component
>   [Connector[AJP/1.3-15009]] SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector
>   [Connector[AJP/1.3-15009]] org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-15009]] SEVERE:
>   Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-bio-15009"] java.net.BindException: Permission denied
>   :15009 SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-15009"] java.net.BindException: Permission
>   denied :15009

11. restarted step 6, this time left IP's as they were, changing only localhost to tomcat-stevenwernercs.rhcloud.com, same result but with original IP's
12. ran out of options online, then I posed this question...
13. then I edited it a lot... 
14. patiently wait :)

That is everything I have done, I am not sure why php isnt finding Java. 
I looked at previous questions didn't find anything helpful. 
Open to anything, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Gears in a non-scable application are not allowed to communicate on any non http/ws port.  So if your php java bridge is trying to communicate with the tomcat instance on 15009 (from what i see above) that is not going to work.  You could only make requests on 80/443/8000/8443.  Can you verify what port the java bridge works over?

Comment: I should have made it clearer, the output shown at '10' is simply the output from running the command at '9'. This is just to launch the Tomcat on the DIY Instance, and before connecting to the php is possible. The port 15009 was selected from the youtube link at '10'.

Comment: I still believe that my comment stands, what port does the php java bridge use to talk to the tomcat server?

Comment: 8080, php connects using this defined parameter

'define("JAVA_HOSTS", "W.X.Y.Z:8080");'

Comment: I've changed the port to 443, 8000, & 8443. Each time same error, with the new port number in the error. 
The instance I am testing it on is senqual-stevenwernercs.rhcloud.com. It is a Tomcat 6 (JBoss EWS 1.0) Cartridge, The DIY version could not complete without failure. 
 
However, when I tried port 80, I did get different behavior, looking into it now: "Fatal error: unknown error: please see back end log for details in /home/stevenw1/public_html/softwareProject/real/inc/Java.inc on line 869"

Comment: I am at a loss, this should not be so complicated. 
If openshift could make an updated tutorial, it would be greatly appreciated. The DIY version from '10' above is all I need, I just think the video is outdated, because following the steps exactly yields  'Permission denied' errors.
otherwise I'll just have to pay for some non-openshift java server.

Comment: try changing your define('JAVA_HOSTS',"http://app-domain.rhcloud.com"); and see if that helps, where you use your app and domain for the tomcat gear

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately results in the same error:
"Fatal error: Uncaught Could not connect to the JEE server :senqual-stevenwernercs.rhcloud.com. Please start it. Or define('JAVA_HOSTS',9267); define('JAVA_SERVLET',false); before including 'Java.inc' and try again. Error message: () thrown in /home/stevenw1/public_html/softwareProject/real/inc/Java.inc on line 989". 
On started, Tomcat 6 (JBoss EWS 1.0) cartridge.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution: https://bitnami.com/cloud

I got it working using Bitnami with Amazon AWS, it provides free service for 1 year, documentation that is easy to follow, and plentiful and up to date, It took less than an hour.

Disclaimer: Using ssh tunnel for port 8080 i configured tomcat as if on localhost, and moved my hosted .php to the 
same microserver that also hosted the tomcat. (I gave up on trying to host php and tomcat separately.)
I have hosted tomcat separately before on my university's tomcat server. But that was a node I had full access to.

I would still like to try Openshifts free solution, although the current resources and methods I've seen seem to no longer be valid. And unfortunately the workarounds are not intuitive enough and are currently over my head. Thank you.